# Access a property in the body of a kubernetes resource using a field path

Tags: go, kubernetes, client-go

I want to get the values of the fields declared in the `downwardAPI` section of a `Pod`.

```yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: sample
  namespace: default
spec:
  containers:
  - image: rpa
    imagePullPolicy: Always
    name: testbot
    volumeMounts:
    - mountPath: /etc/pod-info
      name: pod-info
  volumes:
  - downwardAPI:
      items:
      - fieldRef:
          apiVersion: v1
          fieldPath: metadata.labels
        path: labels
      - fieldRef:
          apiVersion: v1
          fieldPath: metadata.name
        path: pod-name
      - fieldRef:
          apiVersion: v1
          fieldPath: metadata.namespace
        path: pod-namespace
    name: pod-info
```

Using `client-go`, I can use `pod.Spec.Volumes[0].DownwardAPI.Items` to get the item slice including the `fieldPath`. But I would now need to dynamically able to fetch whatever values has been declared in the `fieldPath`. So, from the first item, I would like to access the value of `metadata.labels`. I could do `pod.ObjectMeta.Labels` but I would like to access the field dynamically. In terms of Javascript it would have been something like

```js
var foo="metadata.labels"
var fooarr = foo.split(".")
var bar={
  metadata:{
    labels: "foobar"
  }
}
var temp = oof
for(lm of lmaoarr){
  temp = temp[lm]
}
console.log(temp)
```

How do I do something similar using `client-go`?

Comment: What level are you trying to do this at?  From inside the pod (in which case you should just read the files `/etc/pod-info/pod-namespace`)?  Manipulating the YAML directly in your source tree?  What will you do with these values once you extract them?

Comment: I am working with the [virtual-kubelet](https://github.com/virtual-kubelet/virtual-kubelet/) project and as such I won't have any files at `/etc/pod-info/pod-namespace`. In fact in my implementation, I will need to handle the creation of the above file and hence I need to know the value represented.
I will have API access to the cluster though.

Comment: If you decode ths into a nested map[string]interface{} you can use do what you are doing in javascript more or less.

Answer (score 1):

The standard kubelet code has logic to [translate the downward API fields into environment variables](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/blob/5b1e5387591dd3ad0b3ddacc9e44a6ac7260078e/pkg/kubelet/kubelet_pods.go#L806).  It is neither simple nor generic, though: at the bottom of the stack, only the [specific fields listed in the Kubernetes documentation](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/inject-data-application/downward-api-volume-expose-pod-information/#capabilities-of-the-downward-api) are supported.  It would be incomplete, but not wrong or inconsistent with standard Kubernetes, to just match on these specific fields:

```golang
for _, item := range downwardApiObject.Items {
        switch item.FieldPath.FieldRef {
        case "metadata.name":
                return pod.ObjectMeta.Name
        }
}
```

The actual code:

1. Calls [`pods.ConvertDownwardAPIFieldLabel`](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/blob/5b1e5387591dd3ad0b3ddacc9e44a6ac7260078e/pkg/apis/core/pods/helpers.go#L65) which does some very lightweight normalization and validation: subscripts are only allowed on `metadata.annotations` and `metadata.labels`, only the dozen or so specific field names are allowed, and `spec.host` is rewritten to `spec.nodeName`.
2. Handles the `spec.*` and `status.*` variables that depend on non-metadata fields in the pod spec or runtime data.
3. Delegates to [`fieldpath.ExtractFieldPathAsString`](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/blob/5b1e5387591dd3ad0b3ddacc9e44a6ac7260078e/pkg/fieldpath/fieldpath.go#L46) which knows how to handle the `metadata.*` variables.

The [`k8s.io/kubernetes/pkg/fieldpath`](https://pkg.go.dev/k8s.io/kubernetes/pkg/fieldpath) package contains a couple of helpers that are used in processing the downward API, and a really short answer to your specific question could be just to call `fieldpath.ExtractFieldPathAsString` passing it the Pod object, which will handle the metadata fields but nothing else.